# Get mysql result and using it in a subsequent insert command within the same script

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

So I am having a difficult time getting a variable using a mysql search command and then using it in the same script in an insert command. What am I doing wrong?

```
<?php
$usto= $_GET["usto"];
$itena= "item";

$sql = 'SELECT sname FROM login';

$hostname_Database = "blocked";
$database_Database = "blocked";
$username_Database = "blocked";
$password_Database = "blocked";

$mysqli = new mysqli($hostname_Database, $username_Database, $password_Database, $database_Database); 
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
   printf("Connect failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
   exit();
}



$result = $mysqli->query($sql);
if ($result) {
$row = $result->fetch_assoc();
$sql = "INSERT INTO pon(mis, take) 
     VALUES({$row['snake']}, '" . $usto . "')"; //Here, I am trying to use the result from the previous select statement for the variable

$result = $mysqli->query($sql);
if ($result) {

...etc.

}
}
?>
```

Comment: `'SELECT sname FROM login WHERE sname = '$itena'';` Does this not throw an error?

Answer (score 0):

You are vulnerable to [SQL injection attacks](http://bobby-tables.com). Read up about those and fix your code FIRST.

After that, realize that `->query()` calls return a result HANDLE, not the actual field(s) you'd requested in your query. You have to **FETCH** a row of data first:

```
$result = $mysqli->query($sql);
$row = $result->fetch_assoc();

$sql = ".... VALUES ({$row['name_of_field']}  ...)";
```

Note that this is STILL vulnerable to SQL injection.. it's purely to illustrate the query/fetch/insert process.

Comment: I have updated my question to reflect the changes you suggested. Am I doing it correctly?